# No inicia NavigationDrawerActivity "ID does not reference a View inside this Activity"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-imageview, navigation-drawer

Cuando añado un ImageViewer a un CardView para usarlo en un RecyclerView dentro del fragment_home la actividad de NavigationDrawer me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.twittor, PID: 11720
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.twittor/com.example.twittor.PrincipalActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
        at android.app.Activity.requireViewById(Activity.java:3375)
        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.requireViewById(ActivityCompat.java:363)
        at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:58)
        at com.example.twittor.PrincipalActivity.onCreate(PrincipalActivity.java:54)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

**Más Info:**

-El "PrincipalActivity" es la actividad que crea automáticamente Android Studio al agregar un Navigation Drawer

Comment: Cual es la linea 54 de PrincipalActivity.java , agrega al menos el onCreate de esta clase

Comment: El error siempre da en la linea 54, aunque cambie el código de esta, te añado el tramo de código que da los errores `mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery,R.id.nav_slideshow).setDrawerLayout(drawer).build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        setUserData(navigationView);`

Answer (score 0):

En tu Activity PrincipalActivity se carga un layout el cual se especifica a cargar mediante el método  `setContentView()`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.<Id Layout>);
    ...
    ...

}
```

El problema es que en ese layout no se contiene el elemento

Pero en este caso el mensaje:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ID does not reference a
> View inside this Activity

**indica que esa vista con el ID que intentas cargar en realidad existe en tu proyecto pero no dentro de este layout que carga tu Activity.**

Comment: La imagen la introduzco en un CardView para hacer un listado en el RecyclerView la vista que establezco con setContentView es el DrawerLayout que genera automáticamente android studio